# Python3 Regular Expression problem(Data handle)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

i have a question for regex library

```
import re
data = input("type    ", )
with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
     if re.match(data, line):
      print (line)
      break
```

```
data.txt content

HELLO - hi im robot
HI - hello im robot
ADD - pls add
```

My question is. When user type "hello","hi" how can i print data in data.txt? because first words start a big.

Answer (score 1):

You could add re.IGNORECASE:

```
  if re.match(data, line, re.IGNORECASE):
```

In that way, the regex would not be case sensitive anymore.